# Create a Product Subcategory same as Category

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, menu

I'm using magento 2, and I'm building my main navigation by creating the product categories.

I need to have CLOTHING as category and DRESSES as subcategory for CLOTHING , but I also need to have DRESSES next to CLOTHING , as it would be a category , even if is not.. and I want to have same target for both of them.

My question is , do I have to create DRESSES twice ? once as subcategory and once as category , or there is any way to just print the link with his eventually other subcategories ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no out of the box functionality to achieve what you want.

My hacky suggestion:

- create the clothing > dresses subcategory first. This will be the category where all your dresses products go. Take note of the category id.
- create the dresses category.
- now go to **Marketing > URL Rewrites**
- the most recent entry should your new category and look like this: request path: `url-key.html` / target path: `catalog/category/view/id/<id_of_your_dresses_category>`
- click the **Add URL Rewrite** button
- under **Create URL Rewrite** dropdown, ensure you select **Custom**
- now you can fill the form like this:
- Request path: `catalog/category/view/id/<id_of_your_dresses_category>`
- Target path: `catalog/category/view/id/<id_of_your_dresses_subcategory>`
- Redirect type: Permanent
- Then hit the **Save** button.

Comment: I did as you sayd , but when I hit dresses it still goes to the category , and not to CLOTHING - DRESSES , and also the DRESSES menu doesn't drop down the subcategories that CLOTHING - DRESSES - have.. I have reindexed and cleared the cache..

Comment: Hi @Raphael at Digital Pianism , can you please give me a help with this , I did as you said , but still not targeting.. any suggestion ?

Comment: @alexcr I'll make more tests tomorrow and let you know

Comment: ok @Raphael at Digital Pianism , here is an example pretty much of what I'm trying to do with the menu.. http://lasula.com/ thank you for your time !

Comment: @alexcr Yeah I tried this method and it does not work indeed.

Comment: actually it works , is just that you need to delete the old one , cause there must be 2 rewrites , one that get's automaticly created when you create the category , and the second one I've created to redirect it.. so once I've created the second one , I had to delete the first one.. so now is actually redirecting where I want.. is that the most correct way to do it ?

Comment: @alexcr awesome =) out of the box with M2 it is the most correct way I reckon.